# Using VBA, I want to copy all text from MS Word Documents into MS Excel, where Excel lists the Documents and their locations

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I previously asked this question differently, without any code, so it got closed. I have now written some code, and I think I am close, but I'm still running into errors, hoping I can get some help.

Here is what I am basically trying to accomplish, simplified for clarity:

Pretend I have a local folder on my windows computer called "My Documents," and it has the following files in it; all are MS Word Documents:

```
*C:\My Documents\
 Document 1.docx
 Document 2.docx
 Document 3.docx
 Document 4.docx*
```

Separately I have an excel spreadsheet which lists the following:

```
*Filename (A)  Directory (B)            Content (C)  
 Document 1    C:\...\Document 1.docx   blank        
 Document 2    C:\...\Document 2.docx   blank        
 Document 3    C:\...\Document 3.docx   blank        
 Document 4    C:\...\Document 4.docx   blank        *
```

My Word Documents actually have the following text (and nothing else) in them:

```
*Document 1 - I want this text in Column (C), Row 1
 Document 2 - I want this text in Column (C), Row 2
 Document 3 - I want this text in Column (C), Row 3
 Document 4 - I want this text in Column (C), Row 4*
```

I would like to write some visual basic code inside Microsoft Excel that will instruct it to do the following:

For each row in my spreadsheet:

```
 `1. open the file from column B
  2. take all the text in the document (e.g. select all, WholeStory?)
  3. Insert that text in the cell in column D for the row we are working on`
```

... repeat for all rows in my spreadsheet

The result I would expect would be this:

```
*Filename (A)  Directory (B)            Content (C)                           
Document 1     C:\...\Document 1.docx   I want this text in Column (C), Row 1 
Document 2     C:\...\Document 2.docx   I want this text in Column (C), Row 2 
Document 3     C:\...\Document 3.docx   I want this text in Column (C), Row 3 
Document 4     C:\...\Document 4.docx   I want this text in Column (C), Row 4   *
```

In reality, I have almost 300 documents I need to go through, and I'll need to do this exercise multiple times, so I want to automate it.

This is the code I have so far, which I commented to death to try to explain what I think I am doing:

```
Sub GetWordText()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model.
'See under the VBE's Tools|References.

'define variables (i have some extras for different things I tried that didn't work)
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim strDoc As String
Dim strProc As String
Dim r As Long
Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
Dim body As String

'set some settings
wdApp.Visible = False
wdApp.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros

'start working with my excel sheet
 With ActiveSheet

'start loop to go through rows one by one
'starts at r=2 because the sheet has headers
 For r = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  strDoc = .Range("B" & r).Text

'make sure there is actually a file to process
 If strDoc <> "" Then
  If Dir(strDoc) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cannot find:" & vbCr & strDoc, vbExclamation

  'when there is something to process, do this
  Else

    'opens the word doc specified in column B
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strDoc, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)

    '--- EVERYTHING ABOVE THIS WORKS
    '--- NOW I NEED TO COPY THE WORD DOC INTO THE EXCEL CELL IN COLUMN D FOR THIS ROW

    'This next code line throws an error:
    'Object variable or full width vairable not set
    'I thought it would select all of the text in my word doc
    wdApp.Selection.WholeStory

    'then copy the selected text
    wdApp.Selection.Copy

    'paste it into content column for the document's row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & r)

    'close the word doc
    wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True

     End If
   End If
  Next
End With
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need between:

```
'opens the word doc specified in column B
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strDoc, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
```

and:

```
'close the word doc
wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False ' Note False
```

is:

```
'update the worksheet with the document content, merging paragraphs
.Range("C" & r).Value = Replace(wdDoc.Range.Text, vbCr, Chr(182))
```

Finally, after:

```
Next
```

Insert:

```
'reformat the imported data into paragraphs.
.UsedRange.Replace What:="¶", Replacement:=Chr(10), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
```

Comment: Ok so that kind of works, thank you! However... my real documents actually have a lot of text, about 2 pages worth, and that's why I was trying to use "WholeStory" (as compared to my sample which are only little one liners). This code seems to only insert the first line of each document into Excel. Is it easy to tweak to grab the entire content of each word document, regardless of the length?

Comment: @Chris Neither of your two threads on this topic have indicated the existence of more than one paragraph in the documents. In any event, one wouldn't normally try to cram more than a sentence (at most, a paragraph) into a single Excel cell. Moreover, it is not possible to simply copy & paste multiple paragraphs from a Word document into an Excel cell. See revised answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @macropod this is working great I know this isn't a "normal" thing one would want to do - the excel sheet will be virtually unreadable. However, my use case is this, in case someone else encounters something similar... I have a website I need to update with the content of a couple hundred posts (what's in my word documents). It would take forever manually, but I can do it in bulk via CSV import. So my process is 1 - generate list of word documents containing posts, 2 -  use this code to bring the content into my spreadsheet with post id's, 3 - CSV import update website